# How to keep default action input if parameter passed is empty in github action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a workflow with `workflow_dispatch` input default to an empty string.
The workflow uses a local github action having it's custom inputs with their respective default values:

```
# .github/workflow/ci.yml
on:
  push:
    - main
    - wip/**

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      myInput:
        description: An input string
        type: string

jobs:
  myJob:
    steps:
      - name: My action step
        uses: ./.github/actions/my-action
        with:
          myInput: ${{ github.event.inputs.myInput }}
```

```
# .github/actions/my-action/action.yml
name: 'My action'
description: 'An action'
inputs:
  myInput:
    description: An input
    required: false
    default: 'My default input'

runs:
  steps:
    - name: Run
      shell: bash
      run: echo Input: ${{ inputs.myInput }}
```

If the workflow is triggered by a push or if I manually start the workflow with an empty input, I would like the `my-action` action to keep it's default input value `My default input` instead of the empty string.

Any idea if this is possible from the workflow, without tweaking the `my-action` action?

Comment: What is the current behavior of the implementation you shared? The default value of the `action.yml` isn't used as expected?

Comment: There's an issue in the runner about this: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/924

Comment: @GuiFalourd the current behaviour is that `myInput` action input is empty instead of default value.

Comment: @rethab in my case, I want to keep the default of the action inputs if the variable `github.events.inputs.myInputs` does not exist or is empty.
So I don't mind not having a default value from the `workflow_dispatch`

Comment: exactly that is what that issue is about: you cannot pass a default/empty/not-present value to an action, because once you've declared an input higher up, the runner defaults to an empty string and once that reaches the action, the information whether there was no input or an empty input is lost and the action's default is ignored.

Comment: Perhaps you could try this: Change how you pass the input to the action to `myInput: ${{ github.event.inputs.myInput || 'my default' }}`

Comment: rethab: Wouldn't it be easier to check the value inside the action instead of outside, now that if expression are allowed in composite actions? (to avoid duplicating the logic)

Comment: I am very puzzled by this because I think I have the OPPOSITE problem. Have they changed the behaviour? In my case, when I leave the input empty, it ends up being replace by the default. Where what I would want, would be that the input-dependent job gets skipped. Does that make sense? Can someone confirm this?...might need to open my own question on this...

Comment: This also suggest the 'opposite' behaviour:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73404033/how-to-keep-default-action-input-if-parameter-passed-is-empty-in-github-action#